# Solve second order differential equation with cosh using frobenios method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, hyperbolic-functions, frobenius-method

i need to show that the differential equation

$y^{''}+(\cosh(2x)-4)y = 0$

has the solution:

$ y(x) = x+\frac{1}{2}x^3-\frac{1}{40}x^5 -... $

using Frobenius method.

I started by writing cosh(2x) in the form 
$\sum{\frac{4^nx^{2n}}{{2n}!}}$ and assuming a solution of the form $y(x)= \sum{C_nx^{n+s}}$ but once i substitute everything back into the original equation i can't see a way of simplifying all the terms.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MathieuFunction.html

Comment: $\cosh\neq\cos$

Comment: If the writing of the cosh series is not a typo, then this might be the error that you are stumped upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just computation.
\begin{align}
\cosh(2\,x)-4&=-3+2\,x^2+\frac23\,x^4+\dots\\
y(x)&=x+a_2\,x^2+a_3\,x^3+a_4\,x^4+a_s\,x^5+\dots\\
y''(x)&=2\,a_2+6\,a_3\,x+12\,a_4\,x^2+20\,a_5\,x^3+\dots
\end{align}
Multiplying the first two series we get
$$
(\cosh(2\,x)-4)\,y(x)=-3\,x - 3\,a_2\,x^2 + (2 - 3\,a_3)\,x^3 + \dots 
$$
Now sum the last series to the one of $y''$, set the result equal equal to $0$ and solve for the coefficients.

Comment: Thank you so much! P.S  on the second derivative it should be 20 and not 15 i think

Comment: Right.  I have edited.